# best php implementation for autocomplete street, city, and country

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

i am using jquery ui autocomplete to populate the street, city and country. So i'm looking ways to program in php if the param term pass to server by looking up the street name only but not the city and country

example:

> search term: taman melati

search result:

> Taman Melati Utama, Kuala Lumpur

Taman Melati Utama is the street name and Kuala Lumpur is the city name. As you can see, it only match the street name where the mysql only match it in the column street but if the search term like this

> Taman, Kuala Lumpur

I want to match the search term into two fields where the "Taman" will be look up in the street field and "Kuala Lumpur" in the city name

How's that possible in PHP

Comment: What does your datasource look like?

Comment: I may be a bit late, but what you probably mean is, that you have 3 tables in your database, right? One for cities, one for countries and one for streets, is that what you are asking?

Comment: sort of. Just want the way fb implement is the closest solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use keywords in [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: i already use it, you see the problem is the data set return from database is too huge. That is why i want to narrow it down just like i mentioned it above

Comment: You send your keywords back to the server, and then the server loads up a list of things that match.